# How to limit on 1 column and show all values from other column

Tags: sql, postgresql

So, I have an issue I am facing.
I can fix this by doing nested queries but that might make the query slower I think

Suppose I have 3 tables

```
object
-------
object_id
object_name
created_date
```

```
membership
----------
user_id
object_id
user_role
```

```
fields
------
field_id
object_id
access_roles
```

So the query for getting all `object_id-field` combination would become something like

```
select o.object_id, fields.field_id from
object as o inner join membership m on o.object_id=m.object_id
inner join fields f on f.object_id=o.object_id
where m.user_role = any(f.access_roles)
order by created_date
```

Now suppose I have 10 Objects and 10 Fields each (It would be varied, some might have 10, some might have 4)

If I put a limit 10 on the whole query then I would get 1 Object with 10 fields.

What I want to get is 5 objects and all of its fields.
So the result should have 5 objects and all its fields where the user has permission resulting in 50 rows.

I can do this by nested but then the where condition gets repeated.

```
with accessible_field_object as
(select o.object_id, fields.field_id from
object as o inner join membership m on o.object_id=m.object_id
inner join fields f on f.object_id=o.object_id
where m.user_role = any(f.access_roles)
order by created_date limit 5)

select o.object_id, fields.field_id from
accessible_field_object as o inner join membership m on o.object_id=m.object_id
inner join fields f on f.object_id=o.object_id
where m.user_role = any(f.access_roles)
order by created_date
```

And this might not be the best way to do it.

Example Fiddle :
https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/ePupf7jxSsEiiBBdGNHB3m/0

I am trying to find a way to not do the condition check twice

Thanks

-Shaurya

Comment: I got confused with your description...the limit should be applied on fields or on objects? Let's say you have 10 objects and 50 fields for each and your limit is 5, the output should be 5 objects with 50 fields or 10 objects with 5 fields?

Comment: @Kostis The limit should be applied to objects.
So I want all fields of top 5 objects

Comment: Please supply test data values and for those values the desired results, as text - **no images**.

Comment: @Belayer Added a fiddle

Comment: Nesting seems to be the right idea but the problem with your proposed solution is that you're applying the limit to a query with a `WHERE` clause whereas you really need the limit clause on only the object table. See if my solution works; I've tested it on a database of my own with a similar-ish structure but I don't have anything exactly like what you're doing so I'm not 100% sure it'll work.

Answer (score 0):

Your CTE does not have to actually JOIN your other tables. However it does have to ensure it returns only objects that have appropriate membership. You can get that with an `EXISTS` predicate.

```
with accessible_field_object (object_id) as   
     (select object_id 
        from membership m 
       where m.user_id = 1 
         and exists (select null 
                       from fields f 
                      where f.object_id = m.object_id 
                        and m.user_role = any (f.access_roles) 

                    ) 
      order by object_id
      limit 5
     ) --select * from accessible_field_object;
select o.object_id, f.field_id 
  from accessible_field_object  o
  join membership m on o.object_id=m.object_id
  join fields     f on f.object_id=o.object_id
 where m.user_role = any(f.access_roles)
   and m.user_id = 1;
```

I have reproduced your [example here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/bsrHEJbnSYBqepEadHrsqY/0) but using only the above query. Now couple questions about it:

1. Is it shorter? Well No as formatted it is actually somewhat longer.
2. Is it faster? Well that is as toss up. Only extensive testing would
   tell for sure.
3. Is it clearer/ more readable. (IMHO) Yes. The CTE very clearly shows
   what I need out of it.

So **Is it a better query?** Again (IMHO) Yes.  Because of #3 above. But then again I not familiar with your actual data. If this is a stripped down sample this could might be different.  
And finally, does it get rid of the duplicated JOIN conditions? Yes.

Answer (score 0):

There's a simple way to achieve what you want by doing the join *after* the limit, i.e. join the limited select to the other tables. For instance:

```
SELECT o.object_id, fields.field_id FROM (SELECT object_id FROM
object LIMIT 5) AS o
INNER JOIN membership m ON o.object_id=m.object_id
INNER JOIN fields f ON f.object_id=o.object_id
WHERE m.user_role = ANY(f.access_roles)
ORDER BY created_date;
```

Pretty sure this will get you what you want (I've tested it on my own sample database with different tables but a similar structure and it works.)

I changed the capitalization because I find it improves readability to have the SQL terms in all caps and the table and column names in lowercase. But it's not important.

In general, this is a very useful thing to remember: *you can limit queries before joining them*.